# Kubernetes memory and persistenvolumeclaims

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

In kubernetes, for a Pod we specify memory limit and request. There is a PVC which is requested out from PV and created. How do PVC and memory limits corelate during memory allocation and usage, and what if there are conflicts between the two?
I am little confused that any one could have served the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no corelation between PVC and memory limits and requests. PVC provides storage space and memory limit and requests provides RAM.

Comment: If so then can a PVC be shared by multiple pods ?

Comment: It depends on the underlying volume type. Some do support multiple access, though often only in read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

> How do PVC and memory limits corelate during memory allocation and usage, and what if there are conflicts between the two?

There is no direct correlation between **[Resource Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container)** and PVC.

It's common to get a little confuse with the word [memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_memory) as it's a generic term.

Kubernetes uses the word memory as commonly we call **RAM Memory** which has it's [Default Value](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/), and it's [Minimum and Maximum Values](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-constraint-namespace/) set into the cluster configuration.

> If so then can a PVC be shared by multiple pods ?

Yes, [you can share a Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) with diferent pods in the same namespace.

There are many types of Storage [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/), which servers different purposes.

A PersistentVolumeClaim [(PVC)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) is used to mount a [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) into a Pod.